# Swift do-return with guard condition?

Tags: c#, swift, guard

I'm trying to translate some `Swift` code to `C#`. I read the docs, but am not able to grasp what this code block does. I'm not able to run the code, so that makes it even harder. Please help!

```
do {
    oldArray.enumerated().forEach { oldTuple in
        guard case .entry = oldTuple.element else {
            return
        }

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

1. Is this `return` equivalent to a `break`?
2. What is the `guard` condition? Some assignment...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift playgrounds are a great place to explore the language.  Even though you can't run the whole code, you can put a few support pieces around it to see what is happening.

`oldArray` clearly holds some `enum` values.  From your snippet, we can see that one of the values is `.entry`.  I've created an `enum` called `State` for exploration purposes and given it a few cases (`entry`, `foo`, `bar`).

Now throw your snippet into a function and give it an `oldArray` to work with. Add a `print` in the `// Do stuff` section and the truth will be revealed:

```
enum State {
    case entry
    case foo
    case bar
}

func test() {
    let oldArray: [State] = [.entry, .entry, .bar, .entry, .foo]

    do {
        oldArray.enumerated().forEach { oldTuple in
            guard case .entry = oldTuple.element else {
                return
            }

            // Do stuff
            print(oldTuple)
        }
    }
}

test()
```

**Output**

```
(offset: 0, element: __lldb_expr_1.State.entry)
(offset: 1, element: __lldb_expr_1.State.entry)
(offset: 3, element: __lldb_expr_1.State.entry)
```

---

> Is this `return` equivalent to a `break`?

It returns from the closure if the `guard` condition isn't met.

> What is the `guard` condition? Some assignment...?

`.enumerated` turns `oldArray` into a sequence of `(offset: Int, element: State)` tuples.  So the example array becomes `[(offset: 0, element: .entry), (offset: 1, element: .entry), ...]`.  `forEach` takes each of those tuples in turn and assigns it to `oldTuple`.

The `guard` is using *pattern matching* to verify that the current tuple's `element` value is `.entry` otherwise it exits the closure.

The syntax is a bit odd, but it is saying, *to continue beyond this statement, the current tuple's `element` must be a `.entry` otherwise `return` from the closure and abandon processing this element*.

So, this code loops through an array of enums and processes only the ones that are `.entry`.

> What does the `do` do?

Nothing that we can see from your snippet.  If you comment out `do {` and the corresponding `}` the test still does the same thing.  `do` is usually used with *Error handing* to surround calls that might `throw` an error.  `do` statements are usually used with `catch` statements which then catch the thrown error.  By itself, `do { }` just creates a new scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, `return` within the `guard` means the loop will continue with the next element?

Comment: The `return` from `guard` means an early exit for the closure.  The `forEach` will execute the closure for every element of the array.  The early exit just means it is done with that statement, so it skips anything that isn't an `.entry`.  This could have been done with a `for` loop, but in that case the `guard` should do a `continue`:  `for oldTuple in oldArray.enumerated() {
            guard case .entry = oldTuple.element else {
                continue
            }}`